# WPF C# coded lines doesn't recognize coordinates origin

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, line, cartesian-coordinates

I'm exploring graphics capabilities of WPF+C#. Drawing a line with XAML makes what expected. ok.
To draw a simple line with C# code makes something "strange". The coordinates appear **not** where
they should be. Why? The following code should implement a diagonal from (0, 0) to (width, height) of
the container panel of the line.

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Line line1 = new Line
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Black
            };

            Thickness thickness = new Thickness(10, -10, 36, 250);
            line1.Margin = thickness;
            line1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            line1.StrokeThickness = 4;

            line1.X1 = 0;
            line1.Y1 = 0;
            line1.X2 = MainGrid.ActualWidth;
            line1.Y2 = MainGrid.ActualHeight;

            line1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            MainGrid.Children.Add(line1);
        }
```

It doesn't matter what panel you use: canvas, dockpanel, grid, stackpanel, I observed the same
strange and annoying behavior.
[Not showing the diagonal. Not beginning at origin-vertex (0,0): (left,top)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vqqJ.png)

Comment: If you're concerned about it hitting the top-left specifically It looks like the line is going to the corner of the window (including title bar).  As to why there instead of the control...I have no idea.

Comment: Yeah, but what about the (right, bottom) coordinates (ActualWidth, ActualHeight)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `Thickness(10, -10, 36, 250)`. This arbitrary margin is cutting off the rest of the line. Here is a simplified version of your code that correctly draws a line from the top-left corner, to the bottom-right:

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Line line1 = new Line
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.Black,
        StrokeThickness = 4,
        X1 = 0,
        Y1 = 0,
        X2 = MainGrid.ActualWidth,
        Y2 = MainGrid.ActualHeight
    };

    MainGrid.Children.Add(line1);
}
```

Note that `Visibility = Visibility.Visible` is left because `Line` (like most other elements) are visible by default.

Comment: Thanks, both the answer with XAML, and the one with C# make the diagonal right. That's very important for coordinate systems implementation. With XAML i noted that diagonal resizing is made automatic, for the line with C#, man needs to implement binding / event handler to get it right. Anyway, it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much easier with a simple path statement - use Stretch="Fill" so there's no need to worry about dimensions

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" Data="M 0,0 L 1,1" Stretch="Fill" />
```